# Should I use "or" or "nor" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Being a photographer, I wasn't my duty to give Sumire these photos
>   personally. But she still didn't know her co-workers well. **Or/Nor**
>   the other way around.

Should it be "or" or "nor"? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **nor** since it is a negation, but your sentence

> But she still didn't know her co-workers well. *Or/Nor* the other way around.

can the transformed to

> But she still didn't know her co-workers well. **Nor** did they know her.

and could be expressed more clearly as

> But she and her coworkers didn't know each other well.